# /e/ OS location service jumps between correct and fixed wrong location

Tags: lineageos, geolocation, location-services

I have /e/ OS 1.18 installed on my phone.

Ever since I've started using /e/ OS, occasionally my phone would pick a semi-random* fixed location and then alternatingly pass on either my real location or the randomly picked one to apps using the location service.

*By semi-random I mean that it is usually relatively close to me (generally no further than 100km) and usually in a plausible place (a public road, square, railway station...) but otherwise wholly inexplicable.

In the past I had some luck with clearing cache & storage of the System App called Nominatim Geolocator (or similar) – this would fix the problem for a few weeks – but in my current version of /e/ OS I cannot find this app anymore.

In the Advanced Privacy settings, I chose to expose my location and IP address, but this did not help. Neither did clearing cache & storage of Advanced Privacy, nor disabling Advanced Privacy as the mock location app via the developer options.

What can I do to permanently get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that your GPS hardware is not working reliably.  When Location Services is on, it tries its best, using GPS, Cell Tower etc.  In this case its using the Cell-tower location.

Comment: Is there a way to disable usage of cell tower location and force usage of GPS coordinates?